# What is the webserver to go to make a websocket server with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, webserver

I'm trying to get websocket-rails up and run with puma, but it's was quite a pain.
Puma owner recommended run on Rubinius/JRuby for maximum performance. I tried Rubinius but it was quite a pain. Zeus and Sidekiq, the 2 library that I use daily won't play nice with Rubinius, and search around it does seem JRuby has issues as well. So I need to stick with MRI. With MRI in mind, knowing that the connection can be hold for a very long period, may be a few hours, and I would like to serve few hundred people online concurrently, what's the best server to use for my websocket application? (Server as in Unicorn/Thin/Puma)

Comment: Did you ever manage to get websocket-rails and sidekiq working together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and the approved choice of server for Websockets is [Thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/)

Currently we are using a Thin cluster in production with Websocket-Rails handling around hundreds and sometime thousands of people. It's pretty stable and easy on resources.

P.S : Even [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/%20Discourse) uses Thin for their socket implementation.

Comment: W.r.t MRI, Would Thin deliver better performance compare to Puma?

Comment: If you are using MRI Thin would be faster than Puma. Check this http://www.madebymarket.com/blog/dev/ruby-web-benchmark-report.html

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Feel like I've been searching such comparison for ages :D